# ngModel not selecting proper option for select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a `select` element with angular and have the `ng-model` bound to a variable that has the current value the field needs to be set to.

I'm noticing that no matter what I do, angular never assigns the `selected` attribute to the correct `option`.

I define the data for the options and as an example, the existing value:

```
$scope.pasteTypes = [
    {id:0,name:"Paste"},
    {id:1,name:"Snippet"}
  ];
$scope.paste_type = 0;
```

In the template, I build the select:

```
<select 
id="paste_type"
name="paste_type" 
ng-model="paste_type" 
ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in pasteTypes"></select>
```

Comment: it works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/DL7IBotwhjznf5QHhJdz?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, there must be something different between my example and my app. In the app, the paste_type value comes from an object in a service, that's bound to the template with a `$scope.$watch()` function. It works fine for a text input... just not a select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue was that my data (`$scope.paste_type`) was actually set to `'0'` a string, while the keys of the data were to set to numbers. Either defining the keys as strings or parsing the data to an int solves the issue